Conditional moments of Gaussian processes
I encounter the following statement in Statistics of Random Processes (Liptser and Shiryaev):

Consider a 2d Gaussian random process $(\theta_t, \xi_t)$. Let $\mathcal{F}^\xi_t:=\sigma(\xi_s;s\geq t)$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\xi$. Denote $\pi_t(\theta):=\mathbb{E}(\theta_t|\mathcal{F}_t^\xi), \pi_t(\theta^2):=\mathbb{E}(\theta_t^2|\mathcal{F}_t^\xi), \pi_t(\theta^3):=\mathbb{E}(\theta_t^3|\mathcal{F}_t^\xi)$ as the first, second, third order of conditional moments, respectively. Then
$$\pi_t(\theta^3)=3\pi_t(\theta)\pi_t(\theta^2)-2[\pi_t(\theta)]^3$$

The authors also mentioned that

For Gaussian processes, the moments $\pi_t(\theta^n):=\mathbb{E}(\theta_t^n|\mathcal{F}_t^\xi)$ for all $n\geq 3$ can be expressed in terms of $\pi_t(\theta)$ and $\pi_t(\theta^2)$.

However, no proof or detailed explanation is provided in their book.
Is there a name for these properties? Can someone point out a reference for me?

Recall that if $X \in L^p$ and $\mathcal F_n$ is a sequence of increasing $\sigma$-algebras, then $E[X\mid \mathcal F_n] \to E[X\mid \mathcal F_\infty]$ in $L^p$, where $\mathcal F_\infty$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $(\mathcal F_n)_n$.
Given $t$, choose $\mathcal F_n$ which increase to $\mathcal F_t^\xi$. In particular, choose $\mathcal F_n = \sigma(\xi_{t_1},\dots,\xi_{t_n})$ where $(t_m)_m$ is an enumeration of $\mathbb Q \cap [0,t]$. Provided $\xi$ is right continuous, then $\mathcal F_n$ will increase to $\mathcal F_t^\xi$. It follows that $\theta_t \mid \mathcal F_n^\xi$ is Gaussian for every $n$, and consequently so is $\theta_t \mid \mathcal F_t^\xi$.
I would guess that the assumption that $\xi$ have some sort of regularity is not needed, but I don't know how to do without, unfortunately. Perhaps the knowledge that $\mathcal F_t^\xi$ is sets of the form $\{(\xi_{t_1},\xi_{t_2},\dots) \in B\}$ where $(t_n)_n$ is a sequence of times in $[0,t]$  and $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^{\mathbb N})$ may be helpful.

Thanks a lot! But how can we show $\mathcal{F}_n$ increases to $\mathcal{F}_t$ when $\xi$ is right continuouts?

@MingzhouLiu If $\xi$ is right continuous, then $\xi$ is determined by its values on the rationals. Thus, conditioning on $(\xi_s){s\leq t}$ is equivalent to conditioning on $(\xi_s){s\in \mathbb Q \cap [0,t]}$.
